# LDAP CHANGE PASSWORD PHP

Tags: php, ssl, active-directory, ldap, ssl-certificate

I want to change user's password [unicodePwd] on Windows Active Directory using PHP LDAP.

I am using Windows Active Directory via PHP LDAP.

I don't have any issues connection to it.

I don't have any issues collecting data.

I don't have any issues changing attributes using ldap_mod_replace or ldap_modify

except for the "unicodePwd".

*note that this works

```
$user['telephonenumber'] = '1234567890';
```

*note that this does'nt work

```
$user['unicodePwd'] = mb_convert_encoding('my_new_password', "UTF-16LE");
```

// CODE

```
$result = ldap_modify($ldap, $dn, $user);
return ldap_error($ldap);
```

// CODE

// ERROR ON CHANGING unicodePwd

```
ldap_modify(): Modify: Server is unwilling to perform
```

// NO ERROR FOR telephonenumber

- 06/11/2018 Problem,

I can't setup my server to have ldap over ssl.
Already tried installing AD CS, nothing worked so far. Still configuring my server any idea about installing CA(Certificate Authority) to be used in LDAP over SSL?

- 06/20/2018 Problem, NEW PROBLEM

Already setup LDAP OVER SSL, i can also use ldap using the

cmd->ldp; port 389, and 636 with ssl is good.

but when i run it in my php using port 636 or ldaps://servername this is the error,

```
ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server
```

Comment: Is your connection to the LDAP server secured, [as it must be](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248.aspx) to change the password?

Comment: My connection to LDAP is not secured. I use port 389.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be on a [secured connection to modify a password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248.aspx) (and probably other security related options).

Add the following before you call `ldap_bind()`:

```
ldap_start_tls($ldap);
```

This is a good idea even if you aren't trying to change a password as otherwise your bind operation is cleartext and can be sniffed.

---

If you see this error:

> Warning: ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Connect error in ...

You can workaround the issue by adding the following line *before* you call `ldap_connect`:

```
putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');
```

**WARNING**: This disables checking the validity of the LDAP server certificate! Ideally you should add the server certificate (or its signing CA) to your trusted store.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, but i do have an error using ldap_start_tls($ldap);

ERROR : ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Connect error

Is this a server side issue? Should i config a ldaps(ldap over ssl) connection for changing the password?

I am new in configuring windows server, by the way its Windows Server 2012 r2.

Thanks again mate.

Comment: Instead of using StartTLS you should bind to the LDAP-Server using the ldaps-Protocol. It will encrypt ALL network traffic. If you use StartTLS the encryption will be started AFTER the first connection. And as that in PHP usually is a bind which contains the password, that password is sent unencrypted when using StartTLS.

Comment: @heiglandreas As far as I know the recommended way to secure LDAP communications is via StartTLS.  OpenLDAP has gone as far as [deprecating `ldaps://` in favour of StartTLS](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/605.html).  Your comment about the password being sent in plaintext when using StartTLS is incorrect.  Note that `ldap_start_tls` is called **before** `ldap_bind`.

Comment: I stand corrected! I got my information from this (https://forum.forgerock.com/2015/04/ldaps-or-starttls-that-is-the-question/) blogpost. And what I mixed up is that the user needs to explicitly needs to call starttls and therefore it is possible to call ldap_bind before calling ldap_start_tls. Therefore I'd personally prefer using ldaps over starttls as it makes errors less possible.

Comment: I couldn't find a reference of ldaps being deprecaten on OpenLDAP.  Do you have one that you would mind sharing? As I'm in contact with the people maintaining PHPs LDAp-extension that would be very interesting to know!

Comment: A link to openldap.org was contained in my previous comment.  But a comment against the same blog post you linked provides links to OpenLDAP, Red Hat Directory Server, and Apache Directory Server documentation mentioning deprecation:  https://blogs.forgerock.org/petermajor/2015/04/ldaps-or-starttls-that-is-the-question/#div-comment-776

Comment: This *putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');  and *ldap_start_tls($ldap); did not work for me. Does it cost using LDAPS? I couldn't setup my ldaps (ldap over ssl). On server cmd->LDP, I got an error while using the StartTLS button,(Options->TLS->StartTLS). And i cant use the port 636, SSL(checked). But i can use port 389,SSL(unchecked). Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: If your AD isn't configured with a certificate then you won't be able to connect to it via `ldaps://` or StartTLS.

Answer (score 0):

i`m trying to do the same script and have fixed your problem:
ldap_modify(): Modify: Server is unwilling to perform

from : $user['unicodePwd']
to: $user['userPassword']

after using ldap_mod_replace everything is okey. No errors but chainging password script didn`t change my test user password . Don`t know why. There is no error. i have check from ldap server logs.
and see only the connection login from my ip where is the script. but there is no log about changing user password.